# Can not connect MongoDB with Flask in Docker with pymongo client

Tags: python, mongodb, docker, flask

I am trying to connect mongodb with my flask App inside docker. Its is not working . I have tried [this link,](http://containertutorials.com/docker-compose/flask-mongo-compose.html) it works in Mac but I am using Windows.

This is my docker compose file

```
version: '3.4'

services:
  docker_flask_mongo:
    build: .
    ports:
      - '5000:5000'

  mongodb:
    image: mongo:3.4
    ports:
      - '27017:27017'
```

in python flask app I have tried this

```
client = MongoClient(os.environ['DB_PORT_27017_TCP_ADDR'],
            27017)
```

does not work.

Update:

Complete code:

```
import os
from flask import Flask, redirect, url_for, request, render_template
from pymongo import MongoClient

client = MongoClient(os.environ['DB_PORT_27017_TCP_ADDR'],
            27017)
db = client.tododb

app = Flask(__name__)

@app.route('/')
def test_code():
    item_doc = {
        'name': "a" ,
        'description': "b"
    }
    db.tododb.insert_one(item_doc)

    return "done"

if __name__ == "__main__":
    app.run(host='0.0.0.0', debug=True)
```

Complete log:

> Attaching to dockerfolder_mongodb_1, dockerfolder_docker_flask_mongo_1
>   mongodb_1             | 2018-08-27T13:14:18.349+0000 I CONTROL 
>   [initandlisten] MongoDB starting : pid=1 port=27017 dbpath=/data/db
>   64-bit host=e086871a3aeb mongodb_1             |
>   2018-08-27T13:14:18.349+0000 I CONTROL  [initandlisten] db version
>   v3.4.14 mongodb_1             | 2018-08-27T13:14:18.350+0000 I CONTROL
>   [initandlisten] git version: gghgghg..............
>   mongodb_1             | 2018-08-27T13:14:18.350+0000 I CONTROL 
>   [initandlisten] OpenSSL version: OpenSSL 1.0.1t  3 May 2016 mongodb_1 
>   | 2018-08-27T13:14:18.350+0000 I CONTROL  [initandlisten] allocator:
>   tcmalloc mongodb_1             | 2018-08-27T13:14:18.350+0000 I
>   CONTROL  [initandlisten] modules: none mongodb_1             |
>   2018-08-27T13:14:18.350+0000 I CONTROL  [initandlisten] build
>   environment: mongodb_1             | 2018-08-27T13:14:18.350+0000 I
>   CONTROL  [initandlisten]     distmod: debian81 mongodb_1             |
>   2018-08-27T13:14:18.350+0000 I CONTROL  [initandlisten]     distarch:
>   x86_64 mongodb_1             | 2018-08-27T13:14:18.350+0000 I CONTROL 
>   [initandlisten]     target_arch: x86_64 mongodb_1             |
>   2018-08-27T13:14:18.350+0000 I CONTROL  [initandlisten] options: {}
>   mongodb_1             | 2018-08-27T13:14:18.358+0000 I STORAGE 
>   [initandlisten] mongodb_1             | 2018-08-27T13:14:18.358+0000 I
>   STORAGE  [initandlisten] ** WARNING: Using the XFS filesystem is
>   strongly recommended with the WiredTiger storage engine mongodb_1
>   | 2018-08-27T13:14:18.358+0000 I STORAGE  [initandlisten] **
>   See http://dochub.mongodb.org/core/prodnotes-filesystem mongodb_1
>   | 2018-08-27T13:14:18.359+0000 I STORAGE  [initandlisten] error
>   creating journal dir /data/db/journal
>   boost::filesystem::create_directory: No space left on device:
>   "/data/db/journal" mongodb_1             |
>   2018-08-27T13:14:18.359+0000 I STORAGE  [initandlisten] exception in
>   initAndListen std::exception: boost::filesystem::create_directory: No
>   space left on device: "/data/db/journal", terminating mongodb_1
>   | 2018-08-27T13:14:18.359+0000 I NETWORK  [initandlisten] shutdown:
>   going to close listening sockets... mongodb_1             |
>   2018-08-27T13:14:18.359+0000 I NETWORK  [initandlisten] removing
>   socket file: /tmp/mongodb-27017.sock mongodb_1             |
>   2018-08-27T13:14:18.359+0000 I NETWORK  [initandlisten] shutdown:
>   going to flush diaglog... mongodb_1             |
>   2018-08-27T13:14:18.360+0000 I CONTROL  [initandlisten] now exiting
>   mongodb_1             | 2018-08-27T13:14:18.360+0000 I CONTROL 
>   [initandlisten] shutting down with code:100 docker_flask_mongo_1  |  *
>   Serving Flask app "app" (lazy loading) docker_flask_mongo_1  |  *
>   Environment: production docker_flask_mongo_1  |    WARNING: Do not use
>   the development server in a production environment.
>   docker_flask_mongo_1  |    Use a production WSGI server instead.
>   docker_flask_mongo_1  |  * Debug mode: on docker_flask_mongo_1  |  *
>   Running on http://0.0.0.0:5000/ (Press CTRL+C to quit)
>   docker_flask_mongo_1  |  * Restarting with stat dockerfolder_mongodb_1
>   exited with code 100 docker_flask_mongo_1  |  * Debugger is active!
>   docker_flask_mongo_1  |  * Debugger PIN: 470-553-089

and when I go to `localhost:5000` , I am getting the following error

```
pymongo.errors.ServerSelectionTimeoutError
pymongo.errors.ServerSelectionTimeoutError: mongodb:27017: [Errno -2] Name or service not known
```

Comment: replace `os.environ['DB_PORT_27017_TCP_ADDR']` with `mongodb`

Comment: it does not work , `[initandlisten] shutting down with code:100`

Comment: post the full logs

Comment: the log is there

Answer (score 4, accepted):

So here is the solution,

Docker volumes in my machine were full from the previous stuff. so I have removed it using `docker volume prune`

after that in flask code,

```
client = MongoClient('mongodb://mongodb:27017/')
```

now everything works.